# How to upload parameters along with image and audio in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to iPhone programming. Can any body tell me I have upload image and audio along with these parameters

Input Parameters: `caption`, `user_id`, `mobile_tauky_id`, `blauky_id`, `image`, `audio` (`caption` and `blauky_id` are optional)

Using below code i can upload `image`, similarly I want to upload first `caption`, `user_id` means some integer value ex: `3`, `mobile_tauky_id` also some integer value ex: `5`, `blauky_id` also ex: `2`, `image` and `audio`.

Where can I append these parameters First I want append Caption, next `user_id`, then `mobile_tauky_id`, `blauky_id`, after that i have to append `image` and `audio`. Can any body tell me how can I append these parameters in below code. I can only able to append `image` but before that i want to appendcaption, `user_id`, `mobile_tauky_id`.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://182.73.152.59:82/php/tauky_services/codeigniter-restserver-master/index.php/api/uploadClass/uploadTauky/";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSLog(@"%@", request);

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];   

//Image
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",imageData] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response : %@",returnString);

if([returnString isEqualToString:@"Success ! The file has been uploaded"]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Image Saved Successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
NSLog(@"Finish");
```

Comment: Using appendData just like you have done the rest.

Answer (score 7):

you can append one by one parameters such like as:-

```
NSURL *dataURL=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://182.73.152.59:82/php/tauky_services/codeigniter-restserver-master/index.php/api/uploadClass/uploadTauky/"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *dataRqst = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:dataURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

[dataRqst setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

[dataRqst addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

// -------------------- ---- caption ---------------------------\\


[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"captionType\"\r\n\r\n"
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:[caption  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

// -------------------- ---- user_id ---------------------------\

```
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"UserIdType\"\r\n\r\n"
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:[userId  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

// -------------------- ---- mobile_tauky_id ---------------------------\

```
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mobile_tauky_idType\"\r\n\r\n"
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:[mobile_tauky_id  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

// -------------------- ---- blauky_id ---------------------------\

```
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"blauky_idType\"\r\n\r\n"
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:[blauky_id  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


 // media part

// -------------------- ---- Image Upload Status ---------------------------\

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n"
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *mediaType=@"Image";
    NSLog(@"type %@",mediaType);
    [postBody appendData:[mediaType dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    //pass MediaType file

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Data\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // get the image data from main bundle directly into NSData object
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(Your Image);
    // add it to body
    [postBody appendData:imgData];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}

 // -------------------- ---- Audio Upload Status ---------------------------\

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n"
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *mediaType=@"Audio";
    NSLog(@"type %@",mediaType);
    [postBody appendData:[mediaType dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //pass MediaType file

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Data\"; filename=\"myVoice.mp3\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: audio/caf\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/record.mp3", documentsDirectory];

    // get the audio data from main bundle directly into NSData object
    NSData *audioData;
    audioData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:url];
    // add it to body
    [postBody appendData:audioData];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}


// final boundary

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// add body to post

[dataRqst setHTTPBody:postBody];

NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init] ;

//synchronous filling of data from HTTP POST response
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:dataRqst returningResponse:&response error:&error];

//convert data into string
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Response String %@",responseString);
```

Comment: Here values are not uploading.I am getting response like that its :satatus :failed should be empty userid"

Comment: NSString* caption = @"Aslam";
 NSString* user_id = @"10";
 NSString* mobile_tauky_id = @"2";
 NSString* blauky_id = @"0";

Comment: then also its not uploading

Comment: also give type of every parameter

Comment: type of every parameter means?

Comment: when upload data on server then pass a respective type behalf on data,please ask to server side developer about that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30461/discussion-between-kanhaiya-sharma-and-aslam)

Comment: superb...you save my lot time...thank you so much @KanhaiyaSharma

Comment: Always Welcome @Bandish

Comment: Hi, @KanhaiyaSharma, i tried to upload photo to php server, i got the following response :
{"code":412,"message":"Photo not uploaded.","isDisplayToUser":true,"shouldRetry":true,"retryAfterSeconds":""}

Comment: contact to web end developer and say to dry my reqested data and cross check everything